# How to convert values from one range to another with in-equal slopes and real time data?

Tags: calculus, analysis, statistics, graphing-functions, time-series

There are two series , Sa and Sb. Sa ranges always within 0-1 . Sb ranges variably sometimes from 130-145, 2017-2077  and many more etc..

The data points are real time in nature. For each second there is a new data point received such that slopes are in-equal in nature. For example for the 12th(index-11) data point received Sa[11]-Sa[10] != Sb[11]-Sb[10] .

For each data point received, how do I convert the value of Sa into the range of Sb with no information loss?

Note- I have tried using normalisation- converting the values of both the series to [0,1] . The series Sb had higher highs and normalising the series value in each incoming instance distorted the information and trends contained in Sb.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the maximum and minimum possible values for Sb? If not, then you would need after each new data to recalculate the new re-normalized Sb.

Comment: The max and min values are determined on the current instance. There might be higher high or lower low data in the next second.  12,23,34 and then 22 is the new value then min-12, max-34 . In the next instance the series looks like this 12,23,34,22,78 then min-12 , max -78

Comment: Then you would need at every instance to recalculate the whole normalized series

Comment: is there any other data set behaviour which works like the scenario I mentioned?What is this process even called? Any direction would help

Comment: See if my answer is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how useful it is, but you might try something that transforms the $(-\infty,\infty)$ or the $[0,\infty)$ intervals into something finite, like $\arctan$ function. 
So for example, if your values are all positive $\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan{\rm S_b}$ is always in $(0,1)$ interval. It is not a linear transformation, but it preserves the trends (it is monotonic function).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.It does preserve the trend and is very useful for me. But how do I scale the values of Sa into the values of Sb, considering Sb now lies always within 0 and 1 but not necessary starts from 0 and ends in 1

Comment: I am not entirely sure how do you want to scale the values of $\mathrm{S_a}$